# jq: consolidating data into a tree

Tags: json, jq

My data consists of `categories` containing `elements`. Expressed in .csv format, data about the category is repeated with each element. I want to avoid this by storing the data in a .json tree format instead.

How might I consolidate this array of `elements`…

```
[
  {
    "category": "a",
    "comment": "the repetition, oh my",
    "element_foo": 1,
    "element_bar": 10
  },
  {
    "category": "a",
    "comment": "the repetition, oh my",
    "element_foo": 2,
    "element_bar": 20
  }
],
```

…into this array of `categories` containing arrays of `elements`?

```
[
  {
    "category": "a",
    "comment": "the repetition, oh my",
    "elements": [
      {
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": 10
      },
      {
        "foo": 2,
        "bar": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm hoping this is something fairly trivial for `jq` to do - otherwise I'll write something more heavyweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the objects by category and comment, then map the groupings as you'd like:

```
group_by({ category, comment }) | map({
    category: .[0].category,
    comment: .[0].comment,
    elements: map({
        foo: .element_foo,
        bar: .element_bar
    })
})
```